# React native command not responding

Tags: node.js, react-native

I am new to [React Native](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/). I am trying to build my first app in the same. When I try

`react-native init AwesomeApp`

it says

```
This will walk you through creating a new React Native project in /Users/myUser/myFolder
```

and freezes. Any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: It can take some time, be patient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling `react-native` worked.